# Problem when using the same view in tabview along with observable

Tags: nativescript

Ok, i have a tabview with some pages in it, the first and 2nd page fetch data from the web and display it in form of a gridview . Since the UI is exactily the same in both pages i tought of just using one .xml file with it's respective .js /.ts file. and using frames in the tabview to display the same page with some condition in the frame component, like

`<Frame id="firstFrame" defaultPage="home/home-page" isPage='1' />`

and then in my respective .js page use something like

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
page = args.object;
condition = page.frame.isPage
viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.set("items", '');
page.bindingContext = viewModel;};
```

where i store the "condition" in a global scope variable. and use it wherever there is come conditional rendering needed. I also store viewmodel in a global scope.

IT WORKS FINE... kinda...  you see, the 2 pages are Suposed to display different data. but for dome reason, the first page displays an empty page [with no data], and the second wone works fine..

More strange, when i call a function to update the data in the 1st page, it updates it in page 2, and the page one is still blank, if i restar the app, and call the same function in page 2 (remember they are the same page), it updates page one sometimes.

Could it be that both pages are using the same Observable (items)? , if that so, how i´m supposed to bind the Observable to their respective pages?

Oh i should also menction that i use "exports.functioname = functionname" to call the function. It might be that maybe?  i see that the appropiate way to do it is to bind it inside the "page-view-model" file. Could it be that?

Comment: Can you create a sample with Playground?

Comment: I managed to recreate this on playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zgeCrN , i think that it has something to do with async/await, because when i update the observable statically like "viewModel.set("items", The Page is ' + condition);" , it works as expected.

Comment: A workaround that i´ve found is to use 2 viewmodels and update them according to the page . it makes the code a little bit messy but i guess it works. However i would like to know what would be the correct approach to avoid this when reusing pages on a tabview.

Comment: Found another workaround. And is NOT using global variables . https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zgeCrN&v=2 that works as expected. but it sucks so much that the variable binding is not really binded to their own page , instead is binded to the global .js file. I guess it´s the way Nativescript works "<For each XML file that NativeScript parses, the framework also looks for a JavaScript or TypeScript file with the same name and executes the business logic inside it.>" in https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, what you are facing is totally expected. The variable named `condition` is not specific to the page instance so it just retains the last value assigned to it.

When Page 2 is loaded the `condition` variable is overwritten with new value and never updated again.

Comment: This should be the answer logically. But it seems that the binding happens, and works, the word that breaks the binding is the use of "await" , check this playground, it works as expected if i remove the fetched data, and even works with global variables. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zgeCrN&v=5

Comment: It's not the await that breaks, await is nothing but execute a promise and return the value. It's still logically, when you use fetch data, it hits remote url and waits for response and even before it gets back with response the second page gets loaded and the condition value is updated. Without fetch data, your log is executed immediately before second page loads as it wouldn't have to wait for anything.

Comment: Yeah, i managed to do it with settimeout() instead of await, so you are right. ¿any idea how can i bind the variable "condition" to the current page it´s declared? (to avoid overwriting) , i can´t manage to find the solution to that, some suggest using the module pattern but i´ve tried and it doesnt work ;-;

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite anything, then it's wise to keep everything specific to each instance, store them in view model.

Comment: Yeah i´m doing that , but then how i´m supposed to get the reference to the viewmodel ? ;_; if i store it in a variable then it´s gonna overwrite. I´m gonna try using the frame module to get the frame dinamically and then store the page inside it and store it in the viewmodel . It seems odd but i think thats the way to avoid this. Thanks!! c:

Comment: YAAAY IT´S WORKING :D there is hope after all 7u7. Thank you uwu